# Displaying a message when all form validations are successful in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to make a message to appear when all validation in a form are through but it doesn't work

here's my codepen
https://codepen.io/v-ho-ng-hip/pen/ExVRLMv

```
//submit form
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {

    //prevent default submit
    event.preventDefault();

    //run validators
    validateFName();
    validateLName();
    validateEmail();
    validatePass();
    validateConfirmPass();
    validateCity();
    validateGender();

    if (validateFName() && validateLName() && validateEmail() && validatePass() && validateConfirmPass && validateCity() && validateGender()) {
        const successMsg = document.getElementById('success');
        successMsg.innerHTML = 'Registered successfully!';
    };
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to make a message appear when all inputs are through.

here's my html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" id="myForm" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
            <h2>Registration</h2>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 px-4">
                    <label for="firstName" class="control-label">First Name*</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" onfocusout="return validateFName()">
                        <div name="message"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 px-4">
                    <label for="lastName" class="control-label">Last Name*</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" onfocusout="return validateLName()">
                        <div name="message"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email* </label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email" onfocusout="return validateEmail()">
                    <div name="message"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Password* <em>(Password must have more than 8 characters)</em></label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" onfocusout="return validatePass()">
                    <div name="message"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Confirm Password*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="password" id="password2" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" onfocusout="return validateConfirmPass()">
                    <div name="message"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="birthDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date of Birth</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="date" id="birthDate" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div name="message"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="birthDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">City*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="" onfocusout="return validateCity()">
                        <option>
                            Select </option>

                        <option>
                            TP. Hồ Chí Minh </option>
                        <option>
                            Đà Nẵng </option>
                        <option>
                            Hải Phòng </option>
                        <option>
                            Hà Nội </option>
                        <option>
                            Long An </option>
                        <option>
                            Bình Dương </option>
                        <option>
                            Đồng Nai </option>
                        <option>
                            Bà Rịa - Vũng Tàu </option>
                        <option>
                            Other </option>
                    </select>
                    <div name="message"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Gender*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row" id="genderSelect">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="femaleRadio" value="Female">Female
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="maleRadio" value="Male">Male
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="otherRadio" value="Other">Other
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div name="message"></div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <span class="help-block">*Required fields</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
        </form> <!-- /form -->
    </div> <!-- ./container -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

All validations work but the message doesnt. Im a newbie so if there are any tips i can improve im welcoming them all. thanks!

Comment: What does a function like `validateFName()` returns? and why are you calling them each twice?

Comment: Are your validate functions Synchronous?

Comment: @MajidNayyeri it will return boolean. and the first time it's called is when the user click the submit button with without entering any info. the second is that if they all return true, a message will appear.

Comment: Please consider adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi i think yes

Comment: @SMAKSS I have just included my html above. thank you!

Comment: Actually this is not a reproducible example since we don't know how's `validateFName();` or any other of your methods working, so try to create a live demo (using [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Comment: @SMAKSS I've just included a codepen link. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is not very complicated, so whenever you trying to validate one of your inputs, you are calling a function related to that input, some of your existing function does not work as expected like the below one:

```js
function validateFName() {
    // check if is empty
    if (checkIfEmpty(firstName)) return;
    // is if it has only letters
    if (checkIfOnlyLetters(firstName)) return;
    return true;
};
```

### What's happening here?

So the problem here is in both cases of success or failure of **your check attempt you will return `undefined`** like this: `if (checkIfOnlyLetters(firstName)) return;`, because of the second return statement (`return true`) never runs, since the first return statement (`return;`) block the execution of other lanes in this function.

At last your condition:

```js
if (validateFName() && validateLName() && validateEmail() && validatePass() && validateConfirmPass && validateCity() && validateGender())
```

**will return `false` so it won't run the next two lines in your condition anymore.**

### How to fix this?

So you need to make a little change here like this:

```js
function validateFName() {
    // check if is empty
    if (checkIfEmpty(firstName)) return false;
    // is if it has only letters
    if (checkIfOnlyLetters(firstName))
    return true;
};
```

So whenever your check **attempt is successful it will return `true` otherwise it will return `false`.**

**Working demo: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/wvKXxOX)**

**NOTE:** You can read more about `return` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Comment: omg thank you so much!!! I have misunderstood the return statement the whole time